# Pass current class to decorator function

Tags: python, types, decorator, typechecking, python-decorators

I have a decorator method to check the argument types passed to a function.

```py
def accepts(*types):
    def check_accepts(f):
        assert len(types) == f.func_code.co_argcount
        def new_f(*args, **kwds):
            for (a, t) in zip(args, types):
                assert isinstance(a, t), \
                       "arg %r does not match %s" % (a,t)
            return f(*args, **kwds)
        new_f.func_name = f.func_name
        return new_f
    return check_accepts
```

Now, in a class (in `classA.py`), I want a method to only accept arguments of the same class:

```py
class ClassA:
    @accepts(WHATTOPUTHERE)
    def doSomething(otherObject):
        # Do something
```

In other classes I can just put `ClassA` in place of `WHATTOPUTHERE`, but inside `classA.py`, `ClassA` is not known. How can I pass the current class to the `@accepts()` function?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that. That is not my intention, no. Can you explain why that would happen?

Comment: Hrm, come to think of it, that won't happen here; you've reimplemented the same type check that methods *already* do in Python 2; force `self` to be of the same type or a subclass of the current class. But it does appear as if you didn't take into account that `args[0]` is `self` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function based version of the decorator and apply it after the class definition:

```
class ClassA:
    def doSomething(otherObject):
        # Do something
ClassA.doSomething = accepts(ClassA)(ClassA.doSomething)
```

Another way would be write a [Metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) that would automatically apply this after class creation:

```
class Meta(type):

    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
       fields = ('doSomething', ) #Fields on which you want to apply the decorator
       for name, val in dct.items():
           if name in fields:
               dct[name] = accepts(cls)(val)
       return type.__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)


class ClassA(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
    def doSomething(otherObject):
        pass
```

---

Instead of manually doing things like `new_f.func_name = f.func_name`, use [functools.wraps](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps). This would also preserve things like docstring, argument list etc.

```
from functools import wraps
def accepts(*types):
    def check_accepts(f):
        print "inside"
        assert len(types) == f.func_code.co_argcount
        @wraps(f)
        def new_f(*args, **kwds):
```

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't adding a `self` variable to the function `doSomething` and then referencing `args[0]` inside `check_accepts` (provided you add `(*args)` or extra argument to your definition) solve your problem? If the function `doSomething` is supposed to be a class method, still you can outsource this `self`. How?

- add a `self` to some dummy method inside the class
- make a decorator which populates a variable which `accepts` can somehow reach (like metadata)
- make sure to call this additional method before the `doSomething()`
- you've got the class instance! Enjoy!

NOTE: This is not the only way to store metadata like this and use it later, you can do it as you wish.